# New-SelfSignedCertificate to create certificate gives Access Denied

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate

I'm trying to use `New-SelfSignedCertificate` in PowerShell to create a certificate on Windows 10, but the command gives me a permissions error. I'm using an Administrator account.

Command:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=Contoso Software, O=Contoso Corporation, C=US" -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -FriendlyName MyCert -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

Output:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate : CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Access denied. 0x80090010 (-2146893808 NTE_PERM)
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=Contoso Software, ..."
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-SelfSignedCertificate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.NewSelfSignedCertificateCommand
```

Comment: Can you access "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" location,i.e. see the output of ```Get-item "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"```

Comment: Looks like it. No errors but the output is just `Name: My`

Comment: Is `New-SelfSignedCertificate` something you wrote yourself?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 `New-SelfSignedCertificate` is a builtin cmdlet...

Comment: Is the PowerShell window elevated? Is the output of `([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")` True or False?

Comment: @BenH Not in a freshly installed WMF5.1.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633(v=wps.620)), remember that many newer cmdlets are no backported to older operating systems. Assuming that you are running Windows 7 or older it would not be available.

Comment: @BenH its `False`. And yes its the built in `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmd in Windows 10.

Comment: That means the the window isn't elevated. Meaning that window doesn't have admin rights. When you launch PowerShell, right-click run as administrator. Or in the unelevated window, `Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb Runas`

Comment: Blammo thats it, thanks! Write that as an answer if you'd like me to accept it
 

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, although PowerShell.exe is run under a user account with "Administrative Rights". The process cannot use those rights unless it is elevated.

PowerShell windows will add "Administrator:" in the title bar by default. Otherwise you can check if you an administrator by running this command:

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole‌​([Security.Principal‌​.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
```

When you launch PowerShell if done by GUI, you can Right-Click -> Run as Administrator.

Otherwise you can spawn a new process that is elevated by running `Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb Runas`

Answer (score 8):

Create a certificate for your local user account by specifying a different certificate location:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the right answer.  Run-as Privileges are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to store the new certificate in any certificate store - which is possible by just omitting parameter `-CertStoreLocation`, you need elevated rights.

So it comes down to two options:

- Use the certificate store `Cert:\CurrentUser\My`
- Run with elevated rights and use *any* or *no* certificate store

I did expect `New-SelfSignedCertificat` to work without elevated rights when not using a certificate store at all, but

```
PS D:\> $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName 'my.value' -KeyAlgorithm 'RSA' -KeyLength 2048 -Subject 'very important'
New-SelfSignedCertificate : CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Access denied 0x80090010 (-2146893808 NTE_PERM)
```